# groinal response ocd

Tags: women, wudu, taharah, ghusl

I have an ocd problem  called groinal response.so as a 17 year old girl who does not masturbate or watch bad things , this has really affected my life in terms of purity.basically when ever i see, hear or imagine something i get a feeling down there accompanied by liquid that i am not sure wether it is maniy or madhiy or even wadhiy and i have been performing ghusl consecutively and now that it is ramadan it is even harder for me  especially with the fact that during ghusl when washing my private part some liquid comes out.this has really put a damper on the quality of my life at it occurs frequently throughout the day

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your question: First of all if no physical sexual interaction occurs the only possible fluid that comes out is pre-cum or madhiy if it runs out alone, while wadhy would come out with or after urin. Neither of them require ghusl.

Comment: salam, thank you for the reply. but sorry what do you mean by if it runs out alone

Answer (score 0):

> I used to get emotional urethral discharge frequently. Being the
> son-in-law of the Prophet (ﷺ) I requested a man to ask him about it.
> So the man asked the Prophet (ﷺ) about it. The Prophet (ﷺ) replied,
> "Perform ablution after washing your organ (penis)." https://sunnah.com/bukhari:269

So don't worry too much about thoughts, it is not in your control. More you try to suppress it, the more it comes. So just take ablution before you pray. Know that Allah is most pardoning (Afwan), so seek forgiveness in your prayers.